# Outlook breaking Responsive Email Layout

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, responsive-design

I'm building a table-based responsive email with a series of nested tables. My general layout looks like this: 
[image]

With the numbers representing their flow in the html.

Now, in Outlooks '07 and '10, the ones rendered with the Microsoft Word engine, when box 2 reaches a certain height, it appears to be inserting a page/line break, as suggested [here](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010), [here](http://mikethecoder.tumblr.com/post/861597102/outlook-2007-screws-up-spacing-where-page-breaks-would), and [here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css).

I say appears because I don't know of a method to see the code as it is actually interpreted by Outlook/Word in these instances. The problem is that when this break is entered, it forces box/table 3 down to be even with the break, as seen here:
[image]

Now, a number of the sources I've seen suggest, *making* it break with `<tr style="page-break-before: always">` right before it does it by itself, though I think that would work better for people with out two column stacks.

As suggested in the MailChimp article above, I also tried to implement conditional code to target the `<br/>` element:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
br { display: none;}    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

But I didn't see any noticeable difference. I have this layout because it's responsive and folds into a single column for mobile email clients like so:

[image]

All of these elements are nested in a larger table, as well, but I wonder if what I need to do is break the entire document into stacking tables to avoid being overly long, and make a duplicate table/box 3 so that table/box 3 would display on a two column layout and would be the second in order, kept in a table with box/table 1, and then for the one-column mobile display, the duplicate would be set to display beneath the current table/box 2, but that would mess-up my layout **and** require identical updates to two locations.

The tables are currently set-up using the `align:` attribute.

So, is there a way I can make Outlook not break the table, or make it appear the same without changing my document's architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a pretty good grasp of the Outlook page break issue. I would try and design around it, but it will take a bit of experimenting. Using smaller sections might work better.

Another option is to use media queries, but they are not 100% supported, which is probably your motivation to go fluid in the first place. You could try media queries with Outlook conditional tags to force the positioning in Outlook only. Getting messy I know, but that's html-email for you, and may be the only solution to keep a fluid-first layout that is Outlook page-break friendly.

Comment: While it wasn't my preference, this has been how I decided to go, ultimately duplicating two different sets of content in the right-hand column and pushing them into top and bottom stacked tables respectively, allowing for shorter table heights overall, though now I have to tangle with display issues.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Nice article on why to go fluid: http://zurb.com/article/1262/outlook-your-best-worst-enemy-for-respons

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar issue and  I could sort this using following code. The idea here is to go with table td with percentage width (left column will have 75% and the right column will be 25%) and override width in small screen devices using media queries. I will post the code below:

HTML

```
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding:0 0 0 0px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="75%" class="responsive-helper">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="block" align="left" valign="top"  style="padding:25px 0 0;">
                                <img src="images/image1.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt=" " border="0"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="25%" class="responsive-helper">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="block" align="left" valign="top"  style="padding:25px 0 0;">
                                <img src="images/image2.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt=" " border="0"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width:560px) {
    td[class="responsive-helper"] {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

This works well in all versions of Outlook and stacks down in responsive devices.

Comment: Very strange answer. In CSS, you write `td[class= "device-cols"]{}`, but your html doesn't have the `device-cols` class. But even if your html had such a class, I'm sure your solution wouldn't work.